# Windows file sizes

Tags: windows

I'm not sure this applies to Unix or any other OS, other than Windows, hence the title.  When you look at the properties of a file in Windows you see both a Size and a Size on disk.  Could someone explain the difference between the two?

Comment: it surely *does* apply to Unix/Linux/BSD which have the `du` utility to get the "size on disk".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "size on disk" takes into account any compression that might have been applied to the file and the "slack" space at the end of the last allocation unit the file is written to.

NTFS allows for transparent compression / decompression of files. When you compress a file its size remains the same (that is, the size of the data in the file) but the disk footprint of the file will likely be smaller because the NTFS driver will transparently compress the file data as it is written to disk.

Filesystems store files in an atomic allocation unit-- a "cluster" in the case of NTFS and (ex)FAT. The cluster size for a given volume can vary (from 4K to 64K for NTFS, others for other filesystems). A file that is smaller than a single cluster will be stored in a single cluster and, as such, occupy at least one cluster's worth of disk space. It is unlikely that your file's size will be an exact multiple of the cluster size, so the last cluster allocated for the file will contain a combination of file data and "slack" data occupying the unused portion remaining in the last cluster. The "size on disk" counts this "slack" space, too.

It's worth noting that, when it comes to NTFS, very small files can be stored within the master file table (MFT) entry for that file (files where the file name, file data, and file properties combined are 1024 bytes or less). The file will still show a size on disk of the cluster size for the NTFS volume.

Sparse files are a mechanism whereby files that appear very large but contain large areas of zeros with sparse runs of data. NTFS supports sparse files and will report the size on disk as the actual area used by the data runs, excluding the zeros.

Edit:

As syneticon-dj points out, this question certainly does apply to other operating systems, too. The GNU version of the `du` command has an `--apparent-size` argument which will show the file's data size, rather than the on-disk size (which is the default for `du`). There are times when each size is relevant and it's a good idea to know the differences.

Comment: I take it from this that if a file occupies only a portion of a cluster that the rest of that cluster cannot be used by another file.

Comment: That's correct. I'm not aware of any filesystems that do sub-atomic allocations. Typically the "lost" space in the slack allocation unit is so small that it's not a consideration. There could always be a pessimal case (a disk filled w/ allocation unit size + 1 byte files) but that's not likely to happen in normal use.

Comment: I think Netware did partial allocations of unused slack space a long time ago, but given how inexpensive disk space is, it isnt on anyones feature list now.

Comment: @GregAskew - Indeed-- added in Netware 4 in 1994!  http://support.novell.com/techcenter/articles/ana19940603.html  I guess disk cost more back then. The graphic in that page talking about wasted space in KB is amusing.

Comment: Presumably, the Size on Disk figure excludes holes in sparse files.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364930(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A number of filesystems support [block suballocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation): Btrfs, ReiserFS, UFS2.

Comment: NTFS can do tail packing, where extremely small files have their contents placed in the MFT entry itself.  It's not the only filesystem to do that either.  Explorer still reports 4k used on disk for these files though.

Comment: @afrazier - That's a good thing for me to mention-- I wasn't thinking about that when I wrote it but, yeah, files definitely do get stored in the MFT.